# DASHBOARD DE POWER BI A HTML

Tags: python, powerbi, plotly, dash

Tengo un dashboard en power bi y necesito pasarlo a python utilizando ploty y dash. Que formas rapidas y efectivas me recomiendan para hacer este trabajo, Tengo pocos conocimientos en estas librerias. Tengo mis tablas en excel
[image: Este es el dash de power bi]